# Why do I Have to append the method signature with throws Exception when try block is being used?

Tags: java

Below is something that I misunderstood for sure.

throw ex; causes **unreported exception** error.

It demands that it must be CAUGHT or DECLARED... but its is being caught right down here in the try block!!

Why does compiler need the explicit throws Exception in the method signature like this?
REQUIRED METHOD SIGNATURE:

```
private static void div(int i, int j) throws Exception
```

CODES:

```
   public class Exam {
        private static void div(int i, int j) {
            try {
                System.out.println(i / j);
            } catch(ArithmeticException e) {
                Exception ex = new Exception(e);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                div(5, 0);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("END");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're throwing a _new_ exception of type `Exception`, which is a _checked exception_, from inside the catch block. There's nothing to catch this new exception (i.e. it's not surrounded by a try-catch).

Comment: It's being caught and then another exception is thrown.  Don't do this by the way.  You're not adding any "value" to that exception by throwing a different one.  Just remove the try-catch and allow the original exception to be thrown.  You'll be happier in the long run.

Comment: OK, so since you asked.  Your question is poorly researched.  This is basic stuff that you will find described in any Java text book or (good) tutorial.  Lack of research is a good justification for a down-vote.  (Though I didn't.)  (When I searched SO for "unreported exception" in "[java]", I got >500 hits.  Most would give you the answer to this question.

Comment: Your question is also illogical. The `throw` isn't in the scope of the `try`, so your 'when' doesn't apply.

Comment: Did you forget that downvotes and comments are also part of the StackOverflow experience?

Comment: You may want to hover your mouse over the downvote button to see a tool tip telling you when it is appropriate to downvote. Missing research is one of the possible options.

Comment: Hover over the downvote button and read the text.  Poorly researched is *explicitly listed* as a reason to downvote.  And research includes reading the manual.  Or searching for an existing Q&A that addresses your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to do this, btw, is to just allow `ArithmeticException` to end the program if needed.

```
   public class Exam {
        private static void div(int i, int j) throws ArithmeticException {
           System.out.println(i / j);
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
           div(5, 0);
        }
    }
```

Much cleaner and clearer, and the exception provides important debugging information that you will need to find your runtime errors.

---

What I think you'd need to do to catch the second exception is to nest the `try`.  You can have several `catch` for the same `try` and they all only catch one exception, they don't cascade or go in order.  To catch an exception that is thrown by a `catch` you'd need another `try` block.

```
    private static void div(int i, int j) {

      try {   // NESTED HERE

        try {
            System.out.println(i / j);
        } catch(ArithmeticException e) {
            Exception ex = new Exception(e);
            throw ex;
        }

      // THIS GOES WITH THE OUTER NESTED 'try'
      } catch( Exception x ) {
         System.out.println( "Caught a second exception: " + x );
      }
    }
```

But again, you shouldn't do this.  Allowing the original exception to be thrown is the far better choice.

Comment: Thanks I have to really go deeper on this. I'm not 100% on following this through to end of program.

Comment: @Chrips What I think you're missing is that you would need a second, nested `try` to catch the second exception.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Yes that definitely would do it. I was just really confused. THanks

Answer (score 0):

Very thankful for the information I've received from all users comments and answers.
My conclusion:

This **catch** **statement** handles ONE Exception:

```
try{
    stuff
}catch(OnlyThisException ex){
    throw ex;   //CHECKED EXCEPTION
}
```

This **catch** **statement** also handles only ONE Exception and the other is left unhandled:

```
try{
    stuff
}catch(OnlyThisException ex){
    Exception ex = new Exception(e);  //UNCHECKED! Needs catch block
    throw ex;   //CHECKED EXCEPTION
}
```

Comment: "has ONE Exception in it" is irrelevant. There can be more exceptions caught here or even created inside catch (like in example from question). Main problem is that *some* checked exception is still thrown from it and there is no try-catch to handle that thrown exception in the method, which means that method will thrown it outside so it must inform client about that fact by adding `throws ...` in declaration section.

Comment: @Pshemo I'll attempt to edit this but I'm getting detroyed here. And I can't delete the original either

Comment: There is no 'additional exception in the `try` block', and the `catch` statement can catch `OnlyThisException` or any of its derived classes, which makes it a poor name.

Comment: Both code blocks don't have the difference you think they have. Your issue here is `throw ex;`. This throws an exception and as long it is a checked exception it doesn't matter if you just re-throw the caught exception (example one) or wrap it in `Exception` (example two), in both cases these exception aren't handled, thus you'll get the compiler error from the question. I assume the unclear part for you is, that `catch` does not protect you at all for stuff happening inside its own code block. It can only protect your for stuff inside `try {}`. Thrown exceptions inside `catch` are unhandled.

Comment: Oracle provides a bunch of tutorials for Exceptions ins Java, I suggest you may look at them, they may provide helpful information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html